# In a Perl script, how do I determine the shell of the calling program?

Tags: perl

In a Perl script, I want to determine what shell my Perl script was called from.  Motivation is that I have written a wrapper for "module", but before I call module, I need to know what shell to pass along to it as an argument.  If I extract $ENV{"SHELL"}, I can see that is /bin/tcsh in some cases, but this fails when someone invokes /bin/bash from a tcsh shell and then calls my Perl wrapper (it fails to detect the intervening bash shell).  Local variables are of no help since they are not passed along. So how do I figure out what shell my Perl script was called from?

Comment: You haven't said why it matters. What is "module"? The purpose of `SHELL` is to specify the user's preferred shell, regardless of how Perl (or any other program) was launched. If you need to start a shell yourself, you probably *should* use the value of `SHELL`, and not make any assumptions about what shell that might be.

Comment: The environment variable SHELL has absolutely nothing to do with the shell that is running.  It is simply the shell that the user prefers you to use if you need to open an interactive shell.

Answer (score 3):

> *I need to know what shell to pass along to it as an argument.*

What you should use depends on your needs.

- If you want an interactive shell of the user's choice, use `$ENV{SHELL}`.

  That's the whole point of this variable. Just like `EDITOR` and `PAGER`, `SHELL` is used to communicate the user's preference in programs to perform a certain task. If they've misconfigured it, it's on them to fix it.

  If your users are complaining about the wrong shell being used, you could document that the `SHELL` env var is used. You could also imply it by outputting something like `Starting /bin/tcsh (from $SHELL)` before starting the shell.
- If you want to run a shell command, use the shell for which the command was written.

---

> *how do I figure out what shell my Perl script was called from?*

The question as asked isn't answerable, because it relies on the false premise that the program was launched by a shell. A large proportion of processes are created by programs that aren't shells.

There are OS-specific ways of obtaining the parent process's executable (on some systems, at least), but I won't go into details about this because of the lack of specificity and because it's mooted by the first part of the answer.